# PHP PDO execute hangs execution

Tags: php, sql, pdo

When working with a PHP PDO, calling execute on a prepared statement appears to completely hang the execution of the script. The PDO is initialized as follows:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test;charset=utf8', 'root', '');
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT, false);
```

As far as I know, the connection works fine- there is no indication given that it fails. Then, later, I call prepare and then execute, and the execution appears to halt.

```
echo "Hi";                                                      //executes
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
echo "Still Here";                                              //executes
$password = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));
echo "So far so good";                                          //executes
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username=:username");
echo "Still good";                                              //executes
$stmt.execute(array(':username' => $username));
echo "Nope...";                                             //doesn't execute
if($stmt->rowCount() >= 1)
{
    echo "Sorry, that username is already taken.";
}
```

I am not sure what exactly is happening that causes this error, however any help in fixing it would be appreciated.

Comment: change `$stmt.execute(array(':username' => $username));` to `$stmt->execute(array(':username' => $username));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have missed `->` by `.` in execute line.

replace

```
$stmt.execute(array(':username' => $username));
```

by `$stmt->execute(array(':username' => $username));`

you can use binding. you don't need to use `mysql_real_escape_string` in `PDO`

Comment: @Colin Moore: did you test it?

Comment: I doubt I am ever going to live this one down hahaha thank you, a fresh pair of eyes often catches stupid errors like that.

Answer (score -1):

`mysql_real_escape_string` needs a mysql connection,which is not there,since you are connecting with PDO,so your function doesn't do anything.

Besides,WHY are you not using only prepared statements?

Comment: This didn't answer the question, but was rather a comment on other aspects of the question.  While very valid points, this should have been a comment, not an answer.